# Swift playground is not installed

Tags: ipad, swift-playground, ios10

Ok so I installed the apple IOS 10 beta 10.0 on my ipad (Forth-gen) just for swift playground. But its not appearing on the home screen and its not appearing when I search for it. (I have searched playgrounds and swift playgrounds)

Comment: Try installing iOS 10 Beta 2? https://developer.apple.com/download/ No details on whether it might not be available on older hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Swift Playgrounds is loaded on any iPad that can run iOS 10 except for the 4th Generation iPad.

This is most likely due to the 4th generation iPad being the only 32-bit iPad that iOS 10 will support.